# Laravel - Get email to address in a email view.

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In a blade email view is it possible to get the To address?

eg

```
Mail::to('example@local.com')->send(new ActivationEmail( $data ));
```

Accessing the to address in blade eg `{{ $to }}`

I know I can pass it into the $data array `['to' => 'example@local.com']`.

But not wanting to do that because would mean every single email call would require it and adding extra code when not required.

Im using the to email in my unsubscribe link in the layout template and seems stupid to have to pass the email via $data array to every email call just so the unsubscribe link can access it.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: I need to do something like this too. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

We can get it from the magic $__data variable. In the view blade.php file, the following will populate the $to variable with the first to address. the getTo() call returns an array, so you can get multiple addresses if available.

```
<?php
/**@var $message \Illuminate\Mail\Message */    
$message = $__data['message'];
$to      = Arr::first($message->getTo())->toString();
?>
```